# watch to remember its last zero exit output

Tags: linux, bash, memory, proc, watch

I run a process that takes lot of time. Time is not a problem actually but I would like to know how much RAM memory it requires. Process is already running so `/usr/bin/time` is not an option. I found the pid of my process and run

```bsh
watch -n 1 grep VmHWM /proc/3100/status
```

it works nice, I can leave it, do some other work, and just check later what was the value recorded with 1 seconds intervals.
The problem starts if/when a process terminates (either finish job, or get killed because of OOM) because watch replace the last valid output with

```
grep: /proc/3100/status: No such file or directory
```

using option `-e` does not help. Is there a way to make `watch` not refresh output on non-zero exit? or show two most recent ones, so the previous zero exit can still be seen?

Comment: If you know what your process is _called_, you could incorporate `pgrep` into that. I'm not posting this as an answer as I don't have a Linux system to test properly on at the moment.

Comment: @Kusalananda I used `pgrep` to find process id. I don't understand how `pgrep` would help me more, if process terminates then pgrep won't list it anyway, isn't?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I misinterpreted what you were writing and though that you were watching a particular PID, and that the process later restarted with a new PID, and that you wanted to follow that instead.

Comment: I would just use a shell `while` loop for this. `while grep VmHWM /proc/3100/status; do sleep 1; done`.

Comment: @Mikel thanks, you suggestion does the job well. Yet I find it strange that `watch -e` cannot handle that in better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a shell while loop for this.

```
pid=3100
while out=$(grep VmHWM /proc/$pid/status); do
  printf "\r$out     "
  sleep 1
done
printf "\n"
```